# maven-release-plugin and maven 3.0.3

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I'm using the maven release plugin to perform the following with maven-3.0.3

mvn release:prepare

Everything seems to be going fine except that when it creates the tag in SVN, it copies the previous version from the tags folder with the correct label. Any ideas why?

If I switch back to maven-2.2.1, the tagging is correct and the contents of the tagging are the expected ones.

With Maven 2.2.1:

```
[INFO] Tagging release with the label crcib-6.8.5...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --non-interactive copy --file c:\DOCUME~1\markand\LOCALS~1\Temp\maven-scm-1593649573.commit . <url>/svn/repos/crcib/tags/crcib-6.8.5"
```

With Maven 3.0.3:

```
[INFO] Tagging release with the label crcib-6.8.5...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --non-interactive copy --file c:\DOCUME~1\markand\LOCALS~1\Temp\maven-scm-2047728233.commit --revision 6331 <url>/svn/repos/crcib/tags/crcib-6.8.2 <url>/svn/repos/crcib/tags/crcib-6.8.5"
```

Any ideas why? Also, it seems that when using Maven 2, several artifacts are being downloaded before the tagging commences. This is not the case with Maven 3.

Comment: It seems you have minor mistake in your 2nd output (for maven 3): you've mentioned both `crcib-6.8.2` and `crcib-6.8.5`. Is it so? Also compare if plugin versions match in maven output, e.g. `[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.7.2:preapre`.

Comment: that's what exactly the error is. it seems to be copying a the 6.8.2 tag to 6.8.5 as opposed to doing what Maven 2.2.1 does

Comment: how do you compare if plugin versions match? do you know what maven release plugin version I should use for maven 3.0.3? Maybe it's an incompatibility issue!

Comment: I have no experience with this plugin under maven 3. Plugin version is displayed in maven output before the goal is executed. Try to analyze `mvn -X release:prepare`...

Comment: We had this problem as well, but have since moved over to maven 3 completely, so it isn't a problem anymore. The underlying core of mvn is pretty different from 2-3, and many bugs were fixed, so I don't know if you'll get an answer here. Have you checked Jira for maven? You might find it there.

Comment: did you check if the scm section (developerConnection) matches the actual working copy?

Comment: I also recommend you to check the plugin version on the maven 2 and 3 and edit your question. If you can post more details, maybe we can help.

Comment: Have you set remoteTagging or suppressCommitBeforeTag in your properties?

Answer (score 1):

Without your pom.xml, it is difficult to know what's the problem.

The most obvious misconfiguration is probably ins scm, as Wemu said;  :

```xml
<scm>
    <!-- Base URL of repository (trunk/tags/branches independant)-->
    <url>scm:svn:http://svn.my.company.com/repository</url>

    <!-- Current working url (NOT TAG ONE) -->
    <connection>scm:svn:http://svn.my.company.com/repository/trunk/my-project</connection>
    <!-- Current working url -->
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://svn.my.company.com/repository/trunk/my-project</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

This is the version and how I use this plugin :

```xml
 <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.2</version>
      <configuration>
            <tagBase>svn.my.company.com/repository/tags</tagBase>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When you'll use the maven release plugin, this will modify your scm configuration to point to tags.
If it's really a maven 3 issue, i never noticed it.

Could you, please, post you pom.xml (and settings.xml) for further analysis ?